# Как отсортировать числа из текстового файла в массив?

Tags: python, массивы, numpy, матрицы

Есть текстовый файл с большим количеством чисел:

```
123
214
435
435
654
...
432
```

Как правильно сделать следующее: разбить эти числа таким образом, чтобы получился npимерно массив такого вида:

```
[[123, 214, 435, 435, 654, 767, 967, 769, 765, 765, 345, 123, 123], [123, 214, 435, 435, 654, 767, 967, 769, 76,5 765, 345...]....]
```

Начал делать так:

```
ii=1
file = open("file", "r")
for line in file:
  ii = ii+1
  if ii == 14:
     ii=1
```

Делаю по такой логике, но мне кажется, есть более удачный способ.

Comment: `ii = (ii-1)%13 + 1`

Comment: А приведите пример, что означает `[[13 цифр],`

Comment: [[123, 214, 435, 435, 654, 767, 967, 769, 765, 765, 345], [123, 214, 435, 435, 654, 767, 967, 769, 76,5 765, 345]]

Comment: `lines = file.readlines();res=[lines[i:i + 13] for i in range(0, len(lines), 13)]`

Comment: как должна выглядеть результирующая матрица если общее число чисел в фйле не кратно 13? Лишние обрезать или добить нулями??

Comment: Вообще не понял принцип

Answer (score 2):

Если общее число чисел в файле кратно 13, то можно сделать так:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.loadtext(filename).reshape(-1, 13)
```

Если общее число строк/чисел в файле не кратно 13, то следует уточнить вопрос - какой результат ожидается в таком случае